# Low wifi speed after client bridge from G router to N router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-bridge, bridge-router

I have a old belkin F5D7234-4 v5 G router and i wanted internet in two floors.
So i bought a new TP-Link WR841N router. Even this router didnot provide propet signal in other floor.

Used belking g router a main router(floor 1) and installed dd-wrt in tplink router and used it as client bridge (without wire) on other floor(floor 2).

I have a 10Mbps connection.
When only belkin router is on then im able to experience full 10Mbps. But whenever tplink is on n connected to it then im experiencing slow speeds.
Tried changing different channels but none worked out.

What could be the possible solution or workaround to get max speed even when both are switched on.

Comment: Maybe you tried channels that partially overlap.

Comment: No i tried different channels even though it was same.

Comment: I tried 1,6,11.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct - which I infer from your comment about client bridge(without wire), ie you used the tplink as a wireless extender (rather then bridging from wireless to wired), you can't do this without additional hardware (or going wired).  You are wasting half your bandwidth retransmitting the signal.

You could possibly configure the tplink device as an AP Client and feed it into another access point which is on a different channel (at least 3 channels different).

Depending on your house wiring though, you may want to look at doing a wired connection between the access points by using Ethernet over Powerline - this uses adaptors to make a virtual ethernet connection using power cabling - the effectiveness of this can vary depending on your house wiring, but can be very effective - especially if your powerline devices are on the same phase and there isn't something like an RCD between them.

Comment: Thanks davidgo. Wiring is not possible at my home. So, you say without wired connection it is not possible to use full bandwidth...

Comment: Not at all.  I'm saying that you can't get full speed on the second floor using just the tplink router.  You can overcome this limit by using a second device configured as an AP on the second floor, reconfiguring the TPLink as an AP client and then  using a short cable between the TPLink and AP on a different channel you can bypass the limitation.   Alternatively use the electricity wiring to create a virtual wired connection with the help of a couple of powerline devices.

Comment: Sorry david i didnt get a clear picture of what u said. U meant to use 3 devices. 1 on 1st floor on 2devices on 2nd floor.

Comment: Yes.  2 devices on the second floor - one to act as an Access Point client, the other to act as an access point - by using 2 devices you can use 2 different channels and not halve your available bandwidth.

Comment: @Sandeep You might want to consider using powerline networking to connect the wireless routers together.

Comment: @davidgo 2devices on 2nd floor will also be on same SSID but only channel different. But u said there will be 3diff channels but there will b only 2. As the repeater will also have same channel as the main router.

Comment: I didn't say this requires 3 different channels.  It requires 2, but you don't use channels number 1 and 2 because the frequencies overlap and you won't get the throughput - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels